# Can not assign EC2 instance Public IP to Mosquitto MQTT broker

Tags: amazon-ec2, mqtt, mosquitto

I have installed Mosquitto MQTT in one of the EC2 instance(ubuntu) and broker running fine with localhost.

I can able to publish/subscribe in the local machine and as well another EC2 instance (both EC2 in same subnet 172.31.X.X)

Now, i want to connect the broker from a PC outside for (publish/subscribe). So, i tried to configure the broker IP to EC2 instance public IP.

```
VirtualBox:cat /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example
listener 1883 50.24.39.66
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
VirtualBox:
VirtualBox:sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
1495801790: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Fri, 19 Feb 2016 12:03:16 +0100) starting
1495801790: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1495801790: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1495801790: Error: Cannot assign requested address
carun@carun-VirtualBox:~$
```

But, while restarting the broker am getting the above error "Cannot assign requested address"

Done so far,

- Allowed (inboud/outbound) all access to EC2.
- Disabled firewall in EC2
- -Allowed all security level access to EC2 security group.

But no luck,

So question,

1. How to assign a EC2 Public IP to the broker?
2. How can I access MQTT broker out side of world?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Remove the ip address from the listener line and it will bind to all available ip addresses.

Comment: So i need to replace listener to bind?

Comment: by default broker will run on the private ip of EC2 correct...we have to update to public ip for external world to access, rite? please correct me if i wrong.

Comment: @hardillb is saying you should change the line to say "listener 1883" instead of "listener 1883 50.24.39.66". Then it will listen on all IP interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ip address (50.24.39.66) from the end of `listener` line (or just remove  the whole line) to allow mosquitto to bind to all available IP addresses